# kafka connection refused from consumer group thread while polling

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Created a kafka topic X and Y  each with 2 partitions and 1 replica. It is running on 1 docker container called "kafka" linked to second container "zookeeper"

There are 2 Java processes ( maven modules) with exact same version of kafka-client connected to above kafka container running on 9092 and zookeeper.

Both JVM successfully connect to kafka and both are able to check if topics are existing or not. But one JVM is also able to successfully register a consumer group while second JVM is unable to register consumer group.

Consumer thread ( configured to single thread) fails while polling to kafka with connection refused. There are two unique topics and two unique consumer groups.

Do I need two brokers i.e two kafka containers if need to have 2 consumer groups from different JVM ?

```
! java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
! at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
! at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
! at org.apache.kafka.common.network.PlaintextTransportLayer.finishConnect(PlaintextTransportLayer.java:51) ~[app.jar:1.5.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
! at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.finishConnect(KafkaChannel.java:73) ~[app.jar:1.5.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
! at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:323) [app.jar:1.5.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
! at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:291) [app.jar:1.5.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
! at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:260) [app.jar:1.5.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
! at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:232) [app.jar:1.5.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
! at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:180) [app.jar:1.5.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
! at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureCoordinatorReady(AbstractCoordinator.java:193) [app.jar:1.5.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
! at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:248) [app.jar:1.5.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
! at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:1013) [app.jar:1.5.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
! at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:979) [app.jar:1.5.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
! at
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, my bad .. it was port error, one JVM had bootstrap-server for kafka pointing to wrong port instead of 9092 .. it was connecting to zookeeper but failing with kafka